# Worklight Analytics payload

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

Worklight 6.2.0, Mobile Web Environment

The Worklight Info Center offers three formulations for logging an analytic message

```
 WL.Analytics.log('my record');

 WL.Analytics.log({data: [1,2,3]});

 WL.Analytics.log({data: [1,2,3]}, 'MyData');
```

I am successfully using the first of these, but the other two produce no analytics and my fail() function is not fired.

I see in the online tutorials a further formulation

```
 WL.Analytics.log({_activity: "myActivity" });
```

this too produces no output.

Question: Are there other formulations that do work?

Comment: Can try something like `WL.Analytics.log(JSON.stringify({data: [1,2,3]}))` ?

Comment: dhinesh, yes assembling a string as you suggest should be sufficient, however if the documented approaches can be made to work then it's somewhat nicer and if they cannot then the documentation should be updated. Hence I'd like the Worklight folks to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All calls other than

> WL.Analytics.log('my record')

were intended for Analytics features that were not implemented or did not make it into the Worklight 6.2 release. Clearly this is not reflected in the documentation. I will open a defect to either have the logs searchable or have this limitation reflected in the documentation.

If the following call:

> WL.Analytics.log({_activity: "myActivity" });

does not result in activities being searchable in the 'Activites' page of the Analytics console, then this is a defect for Worklight 6.2.

I can confirm that all of the above issues are fixed for the next release of Worklight (whether its through code fixes or documentation). If you need some of these fixes backported to a previous release of Worklight, please open a PMR so that we can begin that process.

Comment: Thanks, I will double check the activity case, we probably will need this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing in the stringify property as true.

```
var obj = {name : "bob", age : 100};

WL.Logger.config({stringify : true, pkg: 'myActivity'});
WL.Logger.debug(obj);
```

If you want a pretty format you could pass in the pretty property

```
WL.Logger.config({stringify : true, pretty : true, pkg: 'myActivity'});
WL.Logger.debug(obj);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am asking about the WL.Analytics API, is this answer relevant?

Comment: My apologies I must have misconstrued your question. I did try to replicate your error but was not able to. Could you provide some more relevant code. This is what I did
       WL.Analytics.log('my record');
    
    WL.Analytics.log({data: [1,2,3]});
    WL.Analytics.log({data: [1,2,3]}, 'MyData');
    WL.Analytics.send();

Also you can also preview your analytics logs by going to localhost:9500/_search