# Worklight analytics, native Java API - what is the additionalMetadata parameter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

WL 6.2.0

The documentation for the Java client-side Analytics API gives:

```
   public static void log(java.lang.String message,
                           org.json.JSONObject additionalMetadata)
```

but does not explain the additionalMetadata. What values can be placed here? How would they surface in the Log search?

Comment: it's not the same API, since it's JS-based, but you may find some additional clues in WL.Analytics.log on this page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_data_capture.html

Comment: Actually, no. That documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See answer to this SO question:  [Worklight analytics payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484559/worklight-analytics-payload)

The documentation describes passing a metadata object, but in Worklight 6.2, this object does not result in searchable text on the Analytics console.  The data is preserved, but not searchable.  This should be fixed, according to the answer to the linked question.

Comment: mike, sorry but that doesn't help. That question (which I also asked) refers to the JavaScript API, and in the example I quote in the question we see a single parameter specifying a value for _analytics, with no message parameter. If this ties up with the Java API I am asking about here, which takes two parameters, it is not at all obvious how that is the case. So I need an answer which clarifies what I should pass as the second parameter for the Java API additionalMeta value. I suspect you're correct that it has no effect, but I need to know.